# autofmt_xdate deletes x-axis labels of all subplots

Tags: python, matplotlib

I use `autofmt_xdate` to plot long x-axis labels in a readable way. The problem is, when I want to combine different subplots, the x-axis labeling of the other subplots disappears, which I do not appreciate for the leftmost subplot in the figure below (two rows high). Is there a way to prevent `autofmt_xdate` from quenching the other x-axis labels? Or is there another way to rotate the labels? As you can see I experimented with `xticks` and "rotate" as well, but the results were not satisfying because the labels were rotated around their center, which resulted in messy labeling.

Script that produces plot below:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from numpy import arange
import numpy
from matplotlib import rc

rc("figure",figsize=(15,10))
#rc('figure.subplot',bottom=0.1,hspace=0.1)
rc("legend",fontsize=16)
fig = plt.figure()


Test_Data = numpy.random.normal(size=20)

fig = plt.figure()
Dimension = (2,3)
plt.subplot2grid(Dimension, (0,0),rowspan=2)
plt.plot(Test_Data)
plt.subplot2grid(Dimension, (0,1),colspan=2)
for i,j in zip(Test_Data,arange(len(Test_Data))):
    plt.bar(i,j)
plt.legend(arange(len(Test_Data)))
plt.subplot2grid(Dimension, (1,1),colspan=2)
xticks = [r"%s (%i)" % (a,b) for a,b in zip(Test_Data,Test_Data)]
plt.xticks(arange(len(Test_Data)),xticks)
fig.autofmt_xdate()
plt.ylabel(r'$Some Latex Formula/Divided by some Latex Formula$',fontsize=14)
plt.plot(Test_Data)
#plt.setp(plt.xticks()[1],rotation=30)
plt.tight_layout()
#plt.show()
```

[image: Figure created by script]

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This is actually a feature of the `autofmt_xdate` method. From the documentation of the [`autofmt_xdate`](http://matplotlib.org/api/figure_api.html?highlight=autofmt_xdate#matplotlib.figure.Figure.autofmt_xdate) method:

> Date ticklabels often overlap, so it is useful to rotate them and right align them. Also, a common use case is a number of subplots with shared xaxes where the x-axis is date data. The ticklabels are often long, and it helps to **rotate them on the bottom subplot and turn them off on other subplots**, as well as turn off xlabels.

If you want to rotate the xticklabels of the bottom right subplot only, use

```
plt.setp(plt.xticks()[1], rotation=30, ha='right') # ha is the same as horizontalalignment
```

This rotates the ticklabels 30 degrees and right aligns them (same result as when using `autofmt_xdate`) for the bottom right subplot, leaving the two other subplots unchanged.

Comment: If you're dealing with subplots you're saver with directly reading out the ticklabel objects from the axes object instead of relying on the global plt.xticks method:
`plt.setp(ax.get_xticklabels(), rotation=30, ha='right')`

Comment: @Chaoste thanks man! I was trying to overcome the usage of `fig.autofmt_xdate()` used to rotate x-axis dates at all subplots since it has a side effect: you only see x ticks for the bottom subplots. Your answer helped me.